# Need CIFS dynamic PV provisionner restricted to a specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes, cifs

I have a kubernetes cluster on baremetal.

I need a CIFS dynamic PV provisionner restricted to a specific namespace. I only want user/pod that have access to namespace_a to be able to store on PV provisioned on CIFS shared_a.

Is there any existing solution available?

Any alternative that would allow me to provision dynamically PV that are backed by a samba nas share while keeping namespace isolation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By design PersistentVolumes are not [namespaced objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#not-all-objects-are-in-a-namespace) but PersistentVolumeClaim are.

To achieve isolation between namespace and Persistent Volume you can [bind PV to PVC.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) It is one-to-one mapping and it "reserves" volume to specific PVC.

You have to specify `claimRef` in PersistentVolume's [`spec`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#persistentvolumespec-v1-core) field:

> ClaimRef is part of a bi-directional binding between PersistentVolume
>   and PersistentVolumeClaim.
>   Expected to be non-nil when bound. claim.VolumeName is the authoritative bind between PV and PVC.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
[...]
spec:
[...]
  claimRef:
    name: claim
    namespace: default
```

And in PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim
spec:
[...]
  volumeName: pv1
```

Comment: Could a dynamic provisioner do this binding automatically? Upon PVC with volumeName, generate a PV  with claimRef to bind to the PVC.